# SubDays problem with the month changing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I built a whole lot of functions depending on `Carbon::today()->subDays(7)` or Carbon function in general, Now when we started September every logic is not taking the last week in consideration, it only calculates the week as if it has September days only.
So is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yep, an exemple of a call, the result you get and the result you were expecting. When calling `subDays(7)` it just call the `DateTime::modify()` with `-7 days` so nothing fancy, and it does not such such bug as days disappearing. As a wild guess, maybe check if you're mixing different timezones or have a Daylight Saving Time change in the range.